# How to load JSON data using call API in angulsr JavaScript?

Tags: angularjs

I try to load JSON data using AngularJS API call but it give me error alert not get data

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://re-pos.in/partnerportal/web-service.php?action=getpartnerdata&partnerkey=WNBOSV'
        }).then(function success(response) {
          alert('Success');
          $scope.myWelcome22 = response.data;
        }, function error(response) {
          alert('Error');
    });
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an error on server side or the url you are hitting. Inspect in chrome and go to networks and see what response is being returned by your server

Comment: how you can say server side error you can hit url your browser data response is given

Comment: I also used "OR" if you read it correctly and suggested to inspect which will give clear idea in that case

Comment: no problem edited 11 mins ago when i was read OR was not shown.

Comment: edited "must" to "may" not "OR" , so you didn't read correctly

Comment: chill dude no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('http://re-pos.in/partnerportal/web-service.php', {
        params:  {action: 'getpartnerdata', partnerkey: 'WNBOSV'}
    }
)
.then(function(response) {
console.log(response);
alert("success");
    // Request completed successfully
}, function(x) {
alert("error");
    // Request error
});
```

try this one may be helpful for you